# Como modificar o último item de uma sequência em Java?

Tags: java

Gente, nem sei se essa é a pergunta para dúvida que tenho, mas vamos lá...
Quero obter a seguinte saída: "V V V V V!".

Primeiro criei um algoritmo simples apenas para simular a saída, **sem ponto de exclamação no final da saída**:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int N, i;
    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

    N = ler.nextInt();
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        System.out.print("V ");
    }
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar e me dar uma sugestão de como fazer esse ponto de exclamação no final da saída?
Desde já, muito obrigada!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma bem simples de resolver é com uma condição dentro do `for`, que escreve o elemento seguido de:

- Espaço caso não seja o ultimo
- `!` caso seja o ultimo

Exemplo:

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    System.out.print("V" + (i < N - 1 ? " " : "!"));
}
```

Saída para `N` de `5`:

```
V V V V V!
```

A condição `i < N - 1` indica se o elemento não é o ultimo, e por isso escreve o `" "`.

Também consegue resolver sem utilizar uma condição dentro do `for`. Para isso pode alterar o limite dele para que vá até penúltimo elemento, e escreve o último manualmente:

```
for(i = 0; i < N - 1; i++){
    System.out.print("V ");
}
System.out.println("V!");
```

O `for` agora vai até ao penultimo devido ao `i < N - 1`, imprimindo os elementos seguidos de espaço, sendo que o ultimo é impresso fora do `for`.
No entanto, desta forma o `N` não pode ser `0`, pois irá imprimir `V!`. Caso queira permitir que o `N` possa ser `0` tem que escrever o `V!` dentro de um `if (n > 0)`.

[Veja esses dois exemplos no Ideone](https://ideone.com/HR80r9)

Comment: Obrigada! As duas soluções deram muito certo! Utilizei a segunda. Até mais!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma String a adicionar os "V" nela e depois adicionar o ponto.
Assim:

```
N = ler.nextInt();
String str = "";

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        srt = str.append("V ");
        System.out.print("V ");
    }

str = str.append("!");
System.out.println(str);
```